# How to re use the same Model for mobile application but do not want to expose the properties for web application using .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on an application where I am going to implement different request models for mobile and web applications but the issue is that the mobile application sends some extra properties that I do not want to expose to the web application how can I achieve this I am done some code and its working but I do not want to repeat my self.

```
 public interface IMobileAppBaseRequestDto
 {
     public string? requestingOrganisationTransactionReference { get; set; }
     public string? userCaseName { get; set; }
     public bool isMerchant { get; set; }
     public bool pushUpdateStatus { get; set; }
     public string? ipInfo { get; set; }
     public string? channel { get; set; }
     public string? appVersion { get; set; }
     public string? languageCode { get; set; }
     public string? deviceId { get; set; }
     public string? deviceMaker { get; set; }
     public string? deviceType { get; set; }
     public string? OS { get; set; }
     public string? pushId { get; set; }
     public string? latitude { get; set; }
     public string? longitude { get; set; }
     public string? msisdn { get; set; }
 }

public class ConsumptionDetailsRequestDto
{
    public string AccountResourceId { get; set; } = null!;
}

  public class MobileAppConsumptionDetailsRequest : ConsumptionDetailsRequestDto, IMobileAppBaseRequestDto
  {
      public string? requestingOrganisationTransactionReference { get; set; }
      public string? userCaseName { get; set; }
      public bool isMerchant { get; set; }
      public bool pushUpdateStatus { get; set; }
      public string? ipInfo { get; set; }
      public string? channel { get; set; }
      public string? appVersion { get; set; }
      public string? languageCode { get; set; }
      public string? deviceId { get; set; }
      public string? deviceMaker { get; set; }
      public string? deviceType { get; set; }
      public string? OS { get; set; }
      public string? pushId { get; set; }
      public string? latitude { get; set; }
      public string? longitude { get; set; }
      public string? msisdn { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: I think that isn't wrong to clearly define the models with all the properties needed, even if you're repeating some of them.

Comment: In this case, I have to expose a separate APIs for Mobile application.

Comment: Why don't you use simple inheritance?

Comment: Yes, I can but if I inherit my request model from appBaseRequest it will expose all the properties for web too which I don't want to

Comment: Just create a base class with the common properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on an application where I am going to implement different
> request models for mobile and web applications but the issue is that
> the mobile application sends some extra properties that I do not want
> to expose to the web application how can I achieve

In order to avoid [repeating yourself (DRY)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#dont-repeat-yourself-dry) and ensure that certain properties are only exposed for mobile applications,

You should better create separate request models for each platform and inherit common properties from a base class or interface. Then, you can use these specialized request models in your application.

For instance, you could take the benefit of [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance)

Let's say, you have a some property which would used both in mobile and web application, so we can make them as base class.

Base Class:

```
public class BaseRequestModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string? RequestDetails { get; set; }
    public string? DeviceType { get; set; }
}
```

Mobile Specific Model:

Now you might need some mobile specific model, but at the same time you would to set `deviceType` to mobile for mobile class and web for web specific model.

In order to implement that, you could do as followoing:

```
public class MobileSpecificRequestModel : BaseRequestModel
{
    public MobileSpecificRequestModel()
    {
        DeviceType = "mobile";
    }

    
    public string? MobileSpecifcProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** Setting `deviceType` to mobile and adding new property those are only required for mobile request. You should customize the class property according to your requirement.

Web Specific Model:

Same logic goes for web application or request:

```
public class WebSpecificRequestModel : BaseRequestModel
{
    public WebSpecificRequestModel()
    {
        DeviceType = "web";
    }

    
    public string? WebSpecificProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Above implementation would ensure [DRY principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#dont-repeat-yourself-dry). Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#dont-repeat-yourself-dry) as well.